# ADC continuous conversion STM32F103

Tags: microcontroller, adc, stm32, interrupts, stm32f10x

I'm facing with a problem regarding continuous acquisition of ADC channel in STM32F103.

I use the interrupt at the end of conversion to call a callback function to store the acquired value.

The problem regards the callback that is called only the first time.

I configured my project using STM32CubeMx for continuous acquisition and interrupt generation.

This is the ADC configuration:

```
hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
{
    Error_Handler();
}

/**Configure Regular Channel 
*/
sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_11;
sConfig.Rank = 1;
sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_71CYCLES_5;
if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
{
    Error_Handler();
}
```

This is my acquisition function:

```
ea_ADC_Err_Code_t ea_ADC_n_data_read(Adc_Channel_t channel, adc_eoc_callback adc_cb) 
{
    ea_ADC_Err_Code_t err_code = ADC_ERR;     
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

    adc_read_value    = 0;
    adc_eoc_cb        = adc_cb;
    n_adc_acquisition = ADC_MAX_CONS_ACQ;

    /* Deinit ADC */       
    //while(HAL_ADC_DeInit(&adc_handler) != HAL_OK);

    /* Initialize ADC */ 
    //HAL_ADC_Init(&adc_handler);

    /* Configure ADC Channel */
    sConfig.Channel = channel;
    sConfig.Rank = 1;
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_71CYCLES_5;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&adc_handler, &sConfig);

    /* Set ADC callback */
    HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(&adc_handler);

    /* ADC Calibration */
    //HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&adc_handler);

    /* Start conversion with interrupt*/
    if (HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&adc_handler) == HAL_OK)
    {
      err_code = ADC_OK;
    }

    return err_code;
}
```

And finally my callback:

```
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
    if (n_adc_acquisition)
    {
        adc_read_value += HAL_ADC_GetValue(&adc_handler);
        n_adc_acquisition--;
        edi_Print_L1("ADC Callback %d\n", n_adc_acquisition);
    }
    else
    {
        HAL_ADC_Stop_IT(&adc_handler);
        adc_read_value = adc_read_value >> ADC_DIVIDE_BY_EIGTH;
        adc_eoc_cb(adc_read_value);
    }
}
```

Did I forget something in the callback?

Comment: Are you clearing the interrupt anywhere?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No. I think that in continuous mode, the interrupt cleaning is not needed. Do I clean IT? Thanks

Comment: I don't feel like digging in the datasheet. But you should. Or just give it a try.

Comment: Hey, now I see. You are not setting the callback properly at all.  But you are just manually calling your `HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback`  so you see it is called.

Comment: An interrupt is the information for you to do something, when you have done you need to re-enable it.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Really? Where I made errors?

Comment: See update to the comment

Comment: @EugeneSh.   HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(&adc_handler);

Comment: Ah, wait. I see. STM code has a weak declaration of a function of the same name, so it is set as a callback automatically?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, I create the callback "HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback" in my ADC library.

Comment: But in any case you should not call it manually as you do

Comment: I not call the callback. I only redefine it in my code. Like st suggest

Comment: `HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(&adc_handler);` this line is calling the function.

Comment: But you should show you `main`, as the flow is unclear.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Ops! you are right! I think the problem is regarding the interrupt. Need I to configure IT for ADC1 and NVIC?

Comment: Again, I don't have time to go deeply in a research here, but you might want to take a look [here](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arm/stm32/adc/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to enabled the ADC interrupts, which can be done something like this:

```
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(ADC_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
```

---

The next thing with HAL's interrupt handling is that there are two weak function declaration.

1. for `void ADC_IRQHandler()`
2. for `void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)`

You have to implement the `ADC_IRQHandler()` first, this will be called when an interrupt is generated by the ADC. Inside this function you have to call the `HAL_ADC_IRQHandler(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)`, parameter is your ADC's handler (`ADC_HandleTypeDef`).

```
void ADC_IRQHandler()
{
    HAL_ADC_IRQHandler(&hadc1);
    //HAL_ADC_IRQHandler(&hadc2); <--- In case of a second ADC
}
```

Now, `HAL_ADC_IRQHandler()` will check every kind of error for you (you can check it in its implementation) and if everything is fine, it will call the `void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)`. As it also has a weak declaration, so you have to implement the function.

```
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
    if(hadc->Instance == ADC1)
    {
        int converted_value = HAL_ADC_GetValue(hadc);
        // Do stuff
    }

    //if(hadc->Instance == ADC2)  // <-- In case of a second ADC
    //{
    //
    //}
}
```

---

In STM32CubeMX, in the ADC1 Configuration window, there is tab called **NVIC Settings**. Here you can enable the global interrupts for ADC1 and ADC2, and if you do so, then STM32Cube will implements the `void ADC_IRQHandler(void)` in the *stm32f1xx_it.c* file.

```
/******************************************************************************/
/* STM32F4xx Peripheral Interrupt Handlers                                    */
/* Add here the Interrupt Handlers for the used peripherals.                  */
/* For the available peripheral interrupt handler names,                      */
/* please refer to the startup file (startup_stm32f4xx.s).                    */
/******************************************************************************/

/**
* @brief This function handles ADC1 and ADC2 global interrupts.
*/
void ADC_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_ADC_IRQHandler(&hadc1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_IRQn 1 */
}
```

---

Also it's just a brief summary, so I suggest to read through the [tutorial](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arm/stm32/adc/), @Eugene Sh showed you.

Comment: Thanks! I configured correctly the ADC IT with STM32Cube and now the adc works well!